# How to test a ".xap" file on a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please tell me step by step process for testing a `.xap` file on a Windows Phone 7 device?

Comment: You've asked 46 questions and accepted 2 answers, were the answers to all the others questions really that unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you must ensure that you meet the following prerequisites:

- Your Windows Phone device is developer unlocked using the Microsoft `Developer Registration Tool` or [Chevron WP7 Labs](http://labs.chevronwp7.com/) unlocker tool.
- You have the Zune client software installed
- You have the Windows Phone development toolkit installed

If you have all that sorted, you can then use the `Application Deployment Tool` to publish your `.xap` file by:

1. Connecting your phone to the computer
2. Open the `Application Deployment Tool`
3. Select "Windows Phone Device" from the drop down
4. Select your `.xap` file
5. Click `Deploy`

There's more information on MSDN
[How to: Use the Application Deployment Tool for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: can i directly test the .xap file in real device without having all above requirements.in android directly they can install apk file.like that directly can we install .xap in our phone ?

Comment: No, you can't.  The phone has to be unlocked in order to deploy a xap file.  

The only way you can deploy to locked phones is to go through the Marketplace.  There is now a beta feature in Marketplace, which will allow you to give a link to the file to up to 99 users, whose Live accounts you have to list (to give them permissions).  In this way they can test without their phones being unlocked.

Comment: There is also the ability to publish a "private" application which will not be searchable in the Marketplace. These private applications can only be installed if you have a direct link to them. This would allow a company to distribute applications which don't apply to the public at large.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Using Visual Studio as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928362%28VS.92%29.aspx).
2. Use the *Application Deployment Tool* as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Note that deploying to a device requires the device to be [developer unlocked and registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769508%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). For this, you must first get an [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership) account.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Need Developer Account First.
2.Zune installation.
3.After Activation of the Account need to register your mobile using windows phone registration tool.
4.Once register your mobile you can able to test the apps in device.
```