# how can i directly test the .xap in real device?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test a “.xap” file on a Windows Phone 7 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157441/how-to-test-a-xap-file-on-a-windows-phone-7-device)

How can i test the .xap file directly in device without connecting to pc .

is it possible in android directly they can install apk file by double click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the XAP file you can upload it to a developer unlocked phone using the Application Deployment tool. (As per [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157441/how-to-test-a-xap-file-on-a-windows-phone-7-device).)

Alternatively you can upload the xap to the app hub for beta or private distribution. You can then send links to those you wish to have the application and they can install it directly from the marketplace. (Note that other differences and restrictions apply to distribution with these methods.)

These are the only ways to load a XAP file onto a phone apart from downloading it from the marketplace.

Windows Phone 7 has a different security model to Android and this prevents the distribution of applications in ways that are permitted on Android.